# Нужно чтобы весь блок jopja находился слева и под по большой картинкой дуба. Просто надо подвинуть текст чуть левее

Tags: html, css

```css
.gradik {
  background: rgb(244, 240, 240);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(244, 240, 240, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 71, 166, 1) 23%, rgba(167, 167, 167, 1) 54%);
  min-height: 100vh;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  padding: 30px 0
}

form {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.d1 {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.d1 input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #7BA7AB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  background: #F9F0DA;
  color: #9E9C9C;
}

.d1 button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border: none;
  background: #7BA7AB;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.d1 button:before {
  content: "\f002";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #F9F0DA;
}

.d1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.typologo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -35%;
  position: absolute;
}

.hmmmmm {
  padding-left: 110%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.hmmmm {
  padding-left: 135%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.hmmm {
  padding-left: 155%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.class {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ihihih {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.razmer {
  height: 410px;
  width: 700px;
  float: left;
}

.razmer1 {
  height: 117px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.pochemutak {
  width: 1px;
}

.perviyrazspanispolzuu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 300px;
}

.arondomdom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: -160px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tojeotlichniistyli.css">
</head>

<body class="gradik">
  <header>
    <div class="d1">
      <form>
        <h3 class="hmmmmm">Регистраия</h3>
        <h3 class="hmmmm">Профиль</h3>
        <h3 class="hmmm">Корзина</h3>
        <img class="typologo" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Искать здесь...">
        <button type="submit"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="ihihih">
      <span class="class">
        <h3>Главная</h3>
        <h3>Новинки</h3>
        <h3>Предзаказ</h3>
        <h3>Скидки</h3>
        <h3>Испытай удачу</h3>
        <h3>HAPPY HOUR</h3>
        <h3>Раздача</h3>
        </span>
      <span class="arondomdom">
        <img class="razmer" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
            <span class="pochemutak">
                <span class="perviyrazspanispolzuu"><h3>Выгодные деньги</h3></span>
      <img class="razmer1" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
      <img class="razmer1" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
      <img class="razmer1" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
      </span>
      </span>
      <div class="jopja">
        <div>
          <h3 class="bigbro">Текстище</h3>
          <div>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 class="bigbro">Текстмще</h3>
          <div>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3 class="bigbro">Текстище</h3>
          <div>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
            <h3>Текст</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>

  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Какие именно "надписи" и какой именно "картинки"? Опиши более подробнее проблему.

Comment: Нужно чтобы надписи в диве jopja были под самой большой картинкой дуба в левой его части

Comment: В диве `jopja` есть несколько блоков с надписями... И пока все рано не понятно что тебе нужно. Все объяснения лучше писать в самом вопросе. Его можно редактировать. ;) Так другим будет удобнее его прочитать.

Comment: Всё, поменял вопрос

Comment: я постараюсь поправить но у тебя ооооочень грязный код, как получишь ответ постарайся его исправить

Comment: в каком смысле граязный

Comment: а ты попробуй сам его исправить

Comment: сразу поймешь о чем я)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. У тебя очень грязный код.
2. Не используй конструкции повторно если в этом нет необходимости. Например `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` - ты зачем-то используешь два раза когда одного за глаза.
3. У тебя очень много прописано классов в `html` файле которые ты не используешь(я их не нашел в твоем css).
4. Не используй `css`-свойства которые конфликтуют друг с другом или которые создают трудности в понимании поведения твоих элементов. Например: твой класс `ihihih` со свойством `display: flex`, а класс `razmer` использует свойство `float`(`float` - это вообще в принципе уже морально устаревшее свойство, которое используется в основном в статьях).
5. Не лепи все свойства которые знаешь в свой проект на абум, пока я редактировал твой код, удалил 60% всех свойств из `css` - чтобы ты понимал поведение элементов на странице от этого не поменялось.
6. Не используй картинки через ссылки, если сервер с которого ты будешь их загружать будет выключен ты останешься без этих картинок.
7. Изучи позиционирование элементов а именно display:(block, flex, grid) и position(absolute, sticky, fixed, relative и т д) - если хочешь писать более менее адекватную верстку.
8. `span`-элемент не блочный, в нем хранится только текст. Не нужно в него упаковывать никакие элементы.

Твой код исправлять уйдет часа 4 не меньше - поэтому я все удалил и написал заново, чтобы ты понял как выравнивать текст слева под картинкой (как я понял из вопроса тебе нужно было это)

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <ul class="menu">
                <a href="#"><li>Пункт1</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Пункт2</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Пункт3</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Пункт4</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Пункт5</li></a>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section class="images">
                <div class="bigImage"></div>
                <div class="smallImages">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="text">
                <div>
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

`style.css`

```
body {
    background-image: url(https://haruproject.space/assets/images/bg.gif);
}

a {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #080;
}

li:hover {
    color: #aa5;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

main {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

p, h1 {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 40px;
}

.images {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bigImage {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    background-image: url(https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.smallImages {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}

.smallImages > div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.text {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

P.S. картинки я оставил загружаться по ссылкам чтобы ты мог посмотреть результат.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за разбор

Comment: @АртурБулиев было бы за что) Если ты хочешь прокачиваться как разработчик - то не просто пиши код, а пиши его больше(чтобы проект рос, чем больше проект тем сложнее его поддреживать) и каждый раз как тебе что-то в нем не нравится исправляй - так ты поймешь как писать относительно чистый код

Comment: Можешь объяснить что это значит .smallImages > div

Comment: @АртурБулиев это css селекторы, проще говоря чтобы тебе не назначать тут классы еще и div-ам ты можешь обратиться к ним через родительский элемент, подробнее написано тут https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp. А ввобще возьми этот сайт себе на заметку я учился по нему, тут найдешь 90% нужной тебе инфы по вёрстке. Когда дойдешь до необходимости применять JS - учи тут https://learn.javascript.ru/, ну а если не сдашься и до бэкэнда доберешься то эти ссылки для тебя (https://www.php.net/docs.php, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/) учись лучше сразу по документации - в ней есть всё.

Comment: Загрузил)) наверное глаза уже разбегаются - сколько всего тут учить))) В любом случае я учился сам и перебрал кучу материалов прежде чем нашел хорошие, эти ссылки сэкономят тебе около месяца времени которое ты бы потратил на поиск годных материалов. Доки по js тут - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript

Comment: очень благодарен